# AWS Elastic Beanstalk customize static folder 403 error page

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I use:

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk and have static `public` folder with my resources, defined in elastic beanstalk `.ebextensions`
- `nodejs` and handle errors there

When I open my web site and go to `example.com/public` I see ugly 403 page, seems not handled by `nodejs` server. I guess the server somehow process this request, see that no permissions and throw 403 before it goes to `nodejs` server.

I suspect that if I decide to remove this fonder from the `.ebextensions` config and define as static folder in `nodejs`, it will work as I expect. But is there some way to use my custom 403 page is case I use `.ebextensions` config?